# How to compose an email when I click on button in android?

Tags: android

I have an edit text and a save button. My edit text is providing email address and there is a send button to send an email with an attachment, but I don't know how to code for file attachment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are a community to help each other learn how to program. We prefer very specific questions so that we can provide specific answers. I suggest you read [ask] for some tips to improve your question in order to get the help you need.

Comment: You need to provide some additional details. You say you have an email address. What about the subject and the body of the email? Where will these come from? Do you know how to make an `onClick()` event for the button? Do you know how to open a network connection to send the email? If you do not know either of these last two things, then you should google for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        email = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    public void SendEmail(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send Email"
        android:onClick="SendEmail"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it

```
 private void sendmail() {
 String   mail=mailid.getText().toString();
 String   msubject=subject.getText().toString();
 String   mbody=body.getText().toString();

    Log.i("Send email", "");
    String[] TO = {mail};
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Static subject "+ msubject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Static body "+ mbody);

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        finish();

    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }}
```